# How to include character in regular expression

Tags: regex

I have this text:

```
x A1 ,A2-A4 xx, xxx A5  xxxx
```

I have this regular expression:

```
[A-Z]{1,3}-?\d{1,3}
```

It gets 4 matches:

```
A1,A2,A4,A5
```

But I need to modify this regular expression to get these 3 matches:

```
A1,A2-A4,A5
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just double the expression:

```
[A-Z]{1,3}-?\d{1,3}(?:-[A-Z]{1,3}-?\d{1,3})?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wD3lH5/1)

Comment: This works exactly as I need, thanks. I hope I will never need regular expressions again...

Comment: @Ondřej " hope I will never need regular expressions again" A ha, like it's going to happen ;-)

Comment: @Ondřej better learn them (it's not that hard), and see how much code you won't need to write ;)